# Develop branch X commits behind Main branch after successful Pull Request

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit

My Develop branch is showing as 2 commits behind the Main branch after I made a pull request merging Develop into Main on GitHub. It's now suggesting to me to do a pull request and merge Main into Develop. I am the only person working on this project so no other commits from other team members could have happened to any branch during this time.

To retrace my steps:

- In git I did a `git pull` on remote Develop branch to update my local Develop branch.
- I created a Feature branch locally from Develop branch using command line git.
- On Feature, I made 3 commits.
- I then checkout my local Develop branch and merged it with Feature branch.
- I then pushed Develop (with its 3 new commits) to remote Develop via git.
- On GitHub I then created a pull request to merge remote Develop with remote Main with the 3 commits.
- Main branch now has all my changes.
- Develop branch on GitHub is saying it is 2 commits behind Main.

I'm confused as to why this is happening. My understanding is that Develop and Main on GitHub would be in sync (both in terms of code and in commits) after the pull request. Both branches are showing the same code however the commits are off. Any idea where I made a mistake in my process and should I pull request Main into Develop to fix this issue? It seems like a messy fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - On GitHub I then created a pull request to merge remote Develop with remote Main with the 3 commits.
> - Main branch now has all my changes.

There's a step missing here: someone (some human, most likely) must have *accepted and executed* the Pull Request.  What did they do at this point?  If they used the big green button labeled <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd>, the result you've seen is what you should expect.  This is GitHub-specific; other repository hosting sites may behave differently.

Aside: Git branch names are case-sensitive.  It's unwise to use mixed case here; use names like `main` and `develop`, not `Main` and `Develop`.  Windows and macOS users may encounter problems from time to time by creating names like `main` while names like `Main` also exist.  The problem here is that while *Git* is case-sensitive, Git sometimes stores the branch name as an OS-level *file*, and the default file systems on Windows and macOS are case-*in*sensitive and therefore cannot store two different files named `main` and `Main`.  Git gets confused by this and bad things happen.

Comment: Thanks Torek. I think you're right there. What would be the correct button to press on GitHub when merging the pull request to ensure that both branches don't show different commits after this is done. Also if rebase squashes the commits, shouldn't the Main branch have fewer commits than Develop? Sorry I use capital letters for the branch names here on SO to distinguish them as branches in the text

Comment: Rebase *copies* commits but does not combine them. Using the green "squash and merge" button copies the commits to a single combined commit, and using the green "merge" button makes a *merge commit*. No matter which of these three ways you do the merge *on* GitHub, the `main` branch will be at least one commit "ahead of" the `develop` branch afterward. That's just how GitHub is. Other hosting sites give you different options, but not GitHub.

Comment: From your own experience with version control and GitHub, what would be the best approach to take? Continue doing the above process with the ```main``` and ```develop``` branches diverging. Or should I do a pull request with ```main``` merging into ```develop``` to fix the discrepancy.

Comment: I've mainly used GitHub at a very-small-every-developer-is-really-good company, and we used a rebase workflow at the time. PRs were just used for reviews; merges were done "by hand" (without merging, using rebase locally). (Elsewhere we used Git without GitHub so none of that really applied. Some of this was pre-GitHub and some was big-corporate-setup self-contained servers.)

Comment: I *believe* the general GitHub design is: users make a branch, work on it, and post a PR. The manager or next-level-up programmer does the merge using whatever method they like and then the individual programmer simply *deletes their branch*. So the fact that your branch falls behind is irrelevant!